# How to hook dynamically loaded dex and libs by packer with frida?

Tags: javascript, android, reverse-engineering, malware, frida

i'm trying to hook java class that is being loaded dynamically by the packer.

i used frida-DexDump to get the original dex but how can i hook its functions ? the function i am trying to hook it's call is a native function( declared this way "public static native void Init(String str, String str2);

").

here is the way i tried but nothing come out

```
Java.perform(function() {
Java.openClassFile('/data/data/com.malware.android/6644448.dex').load();
// Printing all available classes 
var iterator = Java.openClassFile('/data/data/com.malware.android/6984300.dex').getClassNames();

// Here all the elements of the array is being printed. 
for (var j = 0; j < iterator.length; j++) {
    console.log(iterator[j]);
}

var my_class = Java.use("com.lib.connect");
//replace the original implmenetation of the function `Init` with our custom function 
//Init is a native function that it's being affected to Integer variable

my_class.Init.implementation = function(x, y) {
    //print the original arguments
    console.log("original call: Init(" + x + ", " + y + ")");
    //call the original implementation of `Init` with args (2,5)
    this.Init("2", "5");
}
```

});

Question 2 :
by loading the dumped dex into Jadx i can see that the app is loading Native libs from assets folder but the folder or files physically aren't stored in assets folder.
so where can i find those files ? what can i do ? tried dumping the app with gameguardian but nothing shows up
created a script that tried pulling the files from the desired folder once created but i can't see any file there (tried this method because one lib is loaded into app it is being deleted)
here is how it is being called

```
private void Config(Context context) {
    AssetManager assets = context.getAssets();
    new File(context.getFilesDir().getPath() + "/vseh").mkdirs();
    new File(context.getFilesDir().getPath() + "/vseh/mtx").mkdirs();
    String str = context.getFilesDir().getPath() + "/vseh/mtx/global-mtx.dat";
    String str2 = context.getFilesDir().getPath() + "/vseh/mtx/base.apk";
    if (!new File(str2).exists()) {
        try {
            copyFile(assets.open("__ainfo.tsa"), new FileOutputStream(str2));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod -R 644 " + str2);
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try {
        copyFile(assets.open("__info.tsa"), new FileOutputStream(str));
        System.load(str);
        FuckLeecher();
        new File(str).delete();
    } catch (IOException e3) {
        e3.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post two questions that are so different together. Create separate questions for each topic please. Regarding the nonexistent lib: have you tried to use link for it's tools to see file operations like create or delete to see if the native libs exists only a few me in filesystem?

Comment: thank you for your replay, i'm sorry about that but for  me the question aren't different but it's my fault because i can't explain it in good way. BTW i tried to dump all IO but i can't find that missing libs that being loaded! i think i should stop here every one told me that i can't dump jiagu packer in my debut